# gitlab CI docker stalls after 2min

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

gitlab CI docker stalls after 2min

slight code change and same bug across different repos. Ci/CD used to work on these repos?

```
...
Step 4/11 : RUN yarn install
  ---> Using cache
  ---> c75197e0dbaa
 Step 5/11 : COPY babel.config.js babel.config.js
  ---> Using cache
  ---> 482b1ff64322
 Step 6/11 : COPY src src
  ---> d530de056b88
 Step 7/11 : RUN mkdir locales
  ---> Running in f7885ea9a3c3
 ...
```

Link to the GL issue
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/support-forum/issues/5202

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a known issue on gitlab. Change dind service as follows. That should fix your problem.

```
services:
    - docker:19.03.5-dind
```

Comment: Yes, I saw in the meantime and that ticket is referenced in the GL issue